# Autolayout - Screensize based constraints iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have this really weird problem with Autolayouts. I am just not able to find the problem here. Below screenshots use iPhone 7 plus as simulator. 
[image]

The view in black has got four constraints !

1) Horizontally in Centre
2) Aspect Ratio 1:1
3) As shown in below figure
[image]

4) As shown in below figure

[image]

Problem:

On iPhone 7Plus, view size stays 200 * 200 and on iPhone 5s, it gets changed to 149 * 149 and on 6s,it gets changed to 204*204 . It actually should be changed to somewhere between 200*200 and 149*149. Any constraint I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you want to keep size of view fixed irrespective of simulator type. If yes 
1. Probably you can set height and width constraints of view to 200 for both or any value .
Or
2. If you want to vary view size based on size of simulator you can set constraints for regular height, compact width and regular height, regular width separately for both of these